# Passing variables between GUI in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, user-interface

I am new to matlab and haven't got long to produce interlinking GUI. It is a lot easier to work from specific examples. I have found generic examples but do not know which sections are Matlab functions and which need to be edited.  Would it be possible to demonstrate for this code how to pass information from the edittext's into bladedesign.fig and how they would be accessed in bladedesign.fig?

Pushbutton4 is a submit button. edittext9 is a variable text box.

```
function edit9_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit9 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit9 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit9 as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function edit9_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit9 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton4.
function pushbutton4_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton4 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
close(gcf)
openfig(bladedesign.fig)
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure i understand your question.

the fig doesn't "do" anyhthing, it is just there, 
the .m file can update the fig, and the fig will reflect the changes immediately

the %hints you have there are pretty much it.

the hObject, is the object that is invoking the call  , try inserting a break point (F12) in the callback and inspecting what you have in there

in case you want to access other data the "handles" variable has them all (though only on callbacks not on CreateFcn)

so handles.pushbutton4 
and handles.edit9

are the wones you are looking for

Comment: sorry i meant designblade.m 

so in designblade.m i can access the handles from menu.m?

I would simply need to put call the data the same way in designblade.m as i have to do calculations later in menu.m?